# How to pass a cookie from couchd to the client through node.js

Tags: node.js, cookies, couchdb, express

CouchDB has authentication built in through it's _session API (http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Session_API) but I'm having trouble passing the cookie it dishes to the client through node.js

Here's my code (I'm using express.js login is the route):

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
  var request = require('request');

  var userData = {
    "name":req.body.email,
    "password": req.body.password
  };

  request.post({
    'url': 'http://wamoyo.iriscouch.com/_session',
    'json': userData,
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body);
    }

    request('http://wamoyo.iriscouch.com/_session', function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(response.request.req._headers);
      // Write the Cookie
      res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", response.request.req._headers.cookie);
      return res.render('index', { title: 'BasicChat' })
    });
  });

};
```

That doesn't seem to work, and I don't know a good way to debug this either. Any help would rock!

My fallback is the use the Jquery Couch plugin like this: (https://wamoyo.iriscouch.com/loginer/_design/Loginer/attachments%2findex.html) But there's a school of reasons why this would suck.

Also, I realize this code isn't efficient yet, I'm just trying to get it to work for now. Sorry if it's messy.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I found you again dear internet friend :)

`nano` implements this, you can use it if you like:

- https://github.com/dscape/nano#using-cookie-authentication

Here is a blog post about it:

- http://mahoney.eu/2012/05/23/couchdb-cookie-authentication-nodejs-nano/#.T-JYHCtYsm8

And here are is a sample (actual test code from nano)

- https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/master/tests/shared/cookie.js#L15-#L51

Comment: Haha, yes, well, stack is the best place to go for answers.  Ah, I came across that article (http://mahoney.eu/2012/05/23/couchdb-cookie-authentication-nodejs-nano/#.T-KbBeGd92N) Good stuff. This might be silly, but I was trying to avoid storing any cookies on the node layer. I mean if I was going to store those in redis, couldn't I just as easily store them in couch? Or not at all?

Comment: The API in `nano` does not store the cookie, you have to do that yourself. Putting it in Redis is fine